# Must declare the scalar variable in cursor SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, cursors

I have this problem with this code.
I don't know why, because before set values.I declare a variable.

Moreover, How i can execute every results that cursor give

Error message: Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Must declare the scalar variable "@ejecutable".

My code:

```sql
declare @Userdb sysname
declare @ejecutable nvarchar(max)
set @ejecutable = ''
set @Userdb = 'SD-A-YF-LG-D-SQL30_ICCORE_reader';
declare cr1_database cursor local forward_only
for
select 'use ' + d.name + ';
go
if not exist
(
   select 1
    from sys.database_principals dp
    where dp.name = ''' + @Userdb + '''
)
begin
   create user ' + QUOTENAME(@Userdb) + '
   from login ' + QUOTENAME(@Userdb) + '
       with default_schema = dbo;
end
exec sp_addrolemember @RoleName = ''db_datareader''
   , @MemberName = ''' + @Userdb + ''';
go
'
from sys.databases d
where d.database_id > 7
open cr1_database;
fetch next from cr1_database
into @ejecutable;
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
   print (@ejecutable);
   fetch next from cr1_database
   into @ejecutable;
end
close cr1_database;
deallocate E cr1_database;
```

Comment: I don't see how the query will gives that error message

Comment: I don't get an error from this code. (I fixed the presumed typo on the final deallocate line.) Are you running this from SSMS? What version of SSMS? My guess is that your client tool parses the GO insind the single quotes as a batch separator. My SSMS doesn't do that, hence my question of what tool you are using.

Comment: `deallocate E cr1_database;` remove the `E`